# Images load in IE but not Firefox or Chrome

Tags: css, wordpress, imagesource

Hey, I have been working on this site and on the computer I made the site everything seems to be working fine but when I test on another computer the sponsor images seem to try to load in Chrome and Firefox but they don't show, I check the source and the images are there.  The images also work in IE.

The site is currently live @ http://www.dellscast.com any suggestions would be very appreciated since the launch of the site is suppose to be today.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They're loading fine for me. Are you sure you don't have an ad blocker or user stylesheet that might be interfering?

Comment: Yeah they show fine for me too.

Comment: Thanks Su, I tested on a few other computers and my phone and it all seems to be working except for that one computer (Windows 7 with FF 4b10 and Chrome 8) so it must be a computer issue and not a website issue, Thanks for confirming its working I really appreciate it and now that you mention it I do have ad blockers I just didn't think they would interfer since the ads aren't listed! thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hum, I can see the sponsor images loading just fine in FF (v 3.6.13 on win7).
You can try this site to check on more browsers: http://browsershots.org/.

Answer (score 0):

The images are loading fine for me as well. Tested on latest stable versions of the browsers!